# Textfield in tableview cell changes text value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The problem I'm running across, is that when i scroll my tableview, if the Textfields are blank(and the placeholder value is showing), the rows show there corresponding placeholder value just fine. However, if i start going through the table view and entering text inside the textfields, once i scroll down, the previous text field values start showing up in other textfields lower in the tableview. I assume it has something to do with the cell indentifier, but it seems to work just fine with my Labels and uitextfield placeholder, just not the textfield user text input. Any thoughts? Here is the code...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.headerLabel.text = @"some string";
    cell.textField.placeholder = @"some other string placeholder,";
    cell.textField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

And here is the CustomCell

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    if(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){
        headerLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:155.0/255.0 blue:155.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Reg" size:15];

        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:13.0/255.0 green:122/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15];

        [self.contentView addSubview:headerLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:textField];

        [self.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerLabel
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.contentView
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:27 ] ] ;

        [self.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerLabel
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.contentView
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:10 ] ] ;

        [self.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.contentView
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:27 ] ] ;

        [self.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:headerLabel
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:5 ] ] ;

        [self.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.contentView
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:-27 ] ] ;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: You need to save the text as it changes and you need to set each text field's `text` property in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing a backing data source for your table view? The reason you are running into this issue is because of

> [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

This method reuses your cells and because you are not associated the text with an index path, the cell gets reused but keeps the text that you added to it earlier in it's label.

So here is how you might fix it. Let's say you enter some text into a text field. You need to store this data (I usually use an array) and have it correspond to the cells indexPath.row property of the cell that the textfield was modified in. The tableview then uses this data source to populate the labels in the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.headerLabel.text = @"some string";

    //Using your data source array to get your data for each cell
    cell.textField.text = self.myDataSourceTextArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

The harder part will be associating a textfield with a certain index path. I would make the individual cells the delegate for the textfield and then have the cells themselves update your data source whenever their textfield is updated and passing their individual index paths so you can preserve the text for the correct cells.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case i want to decrease a textfield value in tableview using button action which present on same cell

```
-(void)decreaseCount:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[btn superview]superview];

    NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    UITextField *tempText = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:10];

    if ([tempText.text integerValue] >0) {
        tempText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[tempText.text integerValue]-1];

    }

    // in my case I want to update Array
    [self updateArray: btn.tag :tempText.text];

}

// here i have replace the array object as per my need
-(void)updateArray:(int) index :(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableArray * arrayCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:str forKey:@"count"];
    [arrayCount replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];

}
```